# Link is changing in <a> tag

Tags: html

I have a link in my html:

```
<a href="/UserManual/Manual.pdf" target="iframe_a" id="framefile" class="framefile">Manual</a>
```

When I run the page and clicked the link, an error occurs:

> 404 Not Found

I checked the location. It is correct and the file was there.
When I tried to inspect the element. My code looks like this:

```
<a href="/UserManual/Manual.pdfManual" target="iframe_a" id="framefile" class="framefile">Manual</a>
```

It seems that the link text was appended in the `href` attribute. What seems to be the problem?

**Edit:**
Below is my script:

```
<script>
    $("a.framefile").each(function () {
        var $this = $(this);
        var _href = $this.attr("href");
        $this.attr("href", _href + $this.text());
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Nothing's the problem in the code you've shared. Try with a different browser to rule out an unruly browser extension, then turn off JavaScript to rule *that* possibility out.

Comment: I tried running the page in IE and Mozilla, but same problem occurs.

Comment: OK, and when you turn off JavaScript in your browser?

Comment: The appended text in the link is removed, but it not already accessible.

Comment: I'm not sure what "it not already accessible" means. If it's there when JS is on, and it's not there when JS is off, the JS is the problem.

Comment: I've put my script in the question

Comment: Well, there you go. `$this.attr("href", _href + $this.text());` does exactly what you describe - it adds the text of the `<a>` to the `href`. Why did you write that code? What's its purpose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code:

```
$this.attr("href", _href + $this.text());
```

adds the text of the link to its `href`, exactly as you describe.

Remove that code (the entire `<script>`, really). Your JavaScript, as written, serves only one apparent purpose - to break your links.